# IBM db2 driver deployment / installation

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, db2

I'm trying to connect to IBM DB2 database with C# application. At first I've installed `IBM Data Server Driver Package`, which, according to [the documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.install.doc/doc/c0022612.html) is *for applications using ODBC, CLI, .NET, OLE DB, PHP, Ruby, JDBC, or SQLJ, use IBM Data Server Driver Package*. Then I thought I could use `IBM.Data.DB2` assembly and happily connect. It didn't work at all, as the app kept crashing while looking for `db2app.dll` in its current working directory.

Then I installed `IBM Data Server Client`, which has this dll in "bin" directory, which I added to system path. That didn't help, so I copied it to my app's build directory, and it now works. But I don't think that is correct, as I also had to copy `msg\en_US\db2nmp.xml` file to my build directory to get exception error texts.

I think it's wrong to copy all these files from DB2 installation, and I should somehow be able to force `IBM.Data.DB2` assembly to look for its required files in the system path, not in its working directory. I also think that `Data Server Driver Package` should be enough, but I wasn't able to do anything with `IBM.Data.DB2.dll` until I installed the larger `Data Server Client`.

I assume that the problem is on my end, not with IBM, so I'm doing something obviously or subtly wrong.

My question is: How do I use the smaller `IBM Data Server Driver Package` with .NET application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this information that is available in DB2 manual:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.doc/doc/c0010960.html

And perhaps this helps also:
[http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/DB2/DB2%20and%20.NET%20FAQs#DB2and.NETFAQs-WherecanIfindtheDB2.NETproviderandVSAddins%3F](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/DB2/DB2%20and%20.NET%20FAQs#DB2and.NETFAQs-WherecanIfindtheDB2.NETproviderandVSAddins?)

In general, I think you should've installed IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio from here(Requires IBM Registration):
https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/preLogin.do?source=swg-daivs

Comment: This answer i believe has gone stale. The links above no longer work. Can we get some updated information on this? Many Thanks! I'm working around the same issue as well.