# IBM Data Server Provider Azure App service Deployment issue

Tags: db2, azure-web-app-service

I am using IBM.Data.DB.Provider nuget package on my .NET framework application and deployed it to Azure app service. I get the below error message:

```
System.IO.IOException: SQL0035N  The file "C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\clidriver\msg\en_US\db2nmp.xml" cannot be opened.
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Resource..ctor(CultureInfo cultureInfo, String szResFileName, String szMsgPath)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Resources.GetResource(CultureInfo cultureInfo)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Exception.get_Message()
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException.ToString()
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ConnPool.HandleUnknownErrors(String strFncMsg, Exception exception, Boolean bThrow)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ConnPool.EncryptString(String value)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ConnPool.ReplaceConnectionStringParms(DB2Connection connection, String szValue, DB2ConnSettings& pSettings, DB2ConnSettingsInternal& pSettingsInternal, Boolean bAttach, Boolean pushDownStrAppended)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection..ctor(String connectionString)
```

how do I grant the permission to this file? can anyone share your experience in setting up the app service for IBM DB2 data provider?

Comment: You can read the pdf file in my answer carefully, this should help you.

Comment: If you have any progress, you can tell me.

Comment: thanks for your reply jason. I followed the pdf and was able to deploy the code on onprem IIS and it works. The same code and connection string when deployed on azure app service doesn't work

Comment: Pls raise a support ticket on portal for help, msft will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> [You can use the Db2 .NET provider for Cloud to deploy .NET applications which use .NET Framework and connect to Db2 and Informix® database servers. The IBM.Data.DB.Provider is available as a NuGet package. For more information see: .NET Provider for Cloud. This package is supported on Azure App Services (Windows Web Apps for Full .NET Framework).](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.doc/doc/c0070359.html)

## For more details. please [check this pdf file](https://higherlogicdownload.s3.amazonaws.com/IMWUC/UploadedImages/19927c3f-1e9e-4536-a3ed-2bb19cea85ae/DB2AZUREAPPSERVICES_WEBAPPS_USING_CLUD_DRVR.pdf).

**Related Posts**

[1. Connect to informix database windows form application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771336/connect-to-informix-database-windows-form-application)

[2. IBM db2 driver deployment / installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135302/ibm-db2-driver-deployment-installation)